# Could you tell me whether it is adjective or verb at a sentence, "The mall is located..."

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I am reading a vocab book to learn English.

There is a example sentence.

That is, "The mall is located his client's long-lost cousin in Mexico."

At the sentence, the 'located', I was sure it was adjective.

But my colleague said, it is verb, because 'located' is not only adjective,

it is also P.P. + verb. So it is verb.

I would like to make it sure.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: The sentence, *"The mall is located his client's long-lost cousin in Mexico."*  is meaningless.  Please check that you typed it correctly. If you did then I suggest you get a different vocab book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Located" is the past participle of the verb "to locate" (meaning to place or to find).  So it's a verb form, and it has two uses -- 1) as a participial modifier of nouns, working like an adjective or 2) in combination with some form of the verb "to be" (here "is") to make a verb in the passive voice.  I don't understand your example about the mall, so I'll make up my own.  Suppose I write

> I'm completely lost, until -- finally! -- the mall **is located** by my car's
>   GPS.

We can tell this is the passive-voice usage because we can transform the clause into the active voice in three steps:

1. The object of the preposition of agency, "by", (here, "my car's GPS) becomes the subject.
2. The passive becomes the active:  "is located" -> "locates"
3. The subject ("the mall") becomes the object.
   This gives us

> My car's GPS locates the mall.

Now consider the sentence

> The mall **is located** by the river.

Here "located" is a participle that serves as an adjectival complement to "mall," telling us which mall we're talking about.  It's the mall down by the river.  Note that the same three-step trick won't work.  "By" is still a preposition, but it's one of location, telling us where; not agency, telling us who.  If we try it anyway, we get

> The river locates the mall.

Which makes no sense.

Comment: Upvoted for a generally good explanation. But please: in "The mall is located by the river", it's not true that "_located_ is a participle that serves as an adjectival complement to _mall_, telling us which mall we're talking about." This is a predicative, not attributive use - it is telling us something about an already identified mall.

Comment: @hemflit Of course "located" is a predicative adjective:  it appears after the verb.  That's its classification as an *adjective*.  Because that verb is copulative, "located" serves as a subject complement, which is its role in the *sentence*.  Do you have a suggestion for better terminology?

Comment: We may be using the words "predicative" and "attributive" differently then, but that's beside the point. Your answer says that sentence is "telling us _which mall_ we're talking about", and that's definitely not true, the sentence is telling us a property of a specific mall which has already been identified. An example of telling us "which mall" would have been "The mall located by the river is very old (not to be confused with that other mall)". My suggestion: replace "telling us which mall we're talking about" with "telling us a permanent property of the mall" or something along those lines.